# Detect and transform numbers in a string using regular expressions

Tags: regex, scala

How can I use a regular expression and matching to replace contents of a string? In particular I want to detect integer numbers and increment them. Like so:

```
val y = "There is number 2 here"
val p = "\\d+".r

def inc(x: String, c: Int): String = ???

assert(inc(y, 1) == "There is number 3 here")
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `replaceAllIn` with a replacement function is one convenient way to write this:

```
val y = "There is number 2 here"
val p = "-?\\d+".r

import scala.util.matching.Regex.Match

def replacer(c: Int): Match => String = {
  case Match(i) => (i.toInt + c).toString
}

def inc(x: String, c: Int): String = p.replaceAllIn(x, replacer(c))
```

And then:

```
scala> inc(y, 1)
res0: String = There is number 3 here
```

Scala's [`Regex`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex) provides a handful of useful tools like this, including a `replaceSomeIn` that takes a partial function, etc.